# Storing multiple cryptocurrencies using a usb stick as the private key

Tags: ether, wallets, cold-storage, hardware-wallets

currently I am using an electrum wallet on watching only mode and using a usb stick that stores my private key whenever I need to send BTC to someone. I would like to do something similar for my ether and cardano but am having trouble finding an open-source cold wallet alternative that would be compatible with a usb stick. How could I accomplish something similar? What programs can be used? Is there any open source software to do this? Thanks for any responses in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't buy a ledger nano or Trezor?

Comment: I do not think it is worth it to buy one for the amount of crypto I am storing and I think it is safer to use a usb stick with completely open source software instead of the leger nano.

Answer (score 0):

USB can easily be scanned by a virus to retrieve data on your USB. Hardware wallet are better because they can't output sensitive data.

Cold wallet mean cold so better to use a full offline computer or even old phone. You can add BIP39 to it, and MyEtherWallet to sign transaction. I don't know for cardano though, you can't even generate cardano with Ian Coleman's BIP39.

Comment: I'm worried about using a hardware wallet because even that could be running malicious code. I think usb or a raspberry pi is the option I will end up using. Do you know any way to do this on a raspberry pi?